# How would I sent a multi part upload request to Google Storage using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to understand the steps given in this document:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload#sending_a_multipart_upload_request

Step 3, creating the body of the request, is where I'm really confused. The full request needs to look like:

```
 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
 Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
 Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
 Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_ENTIRE_REQUEST_BODY]

 --foo_bar_baz
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "myObject"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[JPEG_DATA]
--foo_bar_baz--
```

So I know how I can set the Content-Type with Angular, so I can get it to be:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
```

But how do I send the body? I need the boundary showing up between the metadata and the jpeg data. I don't even know where to begin to do that.

Could someone shed some light on it?

Comment: Have you found anything? Facing similar issue.
[Please go through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167264/google-cloud-platform-how-to-upload-image-file-into-google-cloud-storage-bucke)