# Google Cloud Platform - How to upload image file into google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, json-api

I am trying to upload Image into google cloud storage bucket using Google Cloud Storage JSON API. The file is getting uploaded but it is not showing anything.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        // Move uploaded file to a temp location
        $uploadDir = 'temp/';
        $filename=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
        $filesize=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];
        $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);

        $authheaders = array(
            "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx(my access token)",
            "Content-Type: image/jpeg",
            "Content-Length:".$filesize

        ); //The access-token has to be generate everytime after one-hour.

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile))
        {
            // Prepare remote upload data
            $uploadRequest = array(
                'fileName' => basename($uploadFile),
                'fileData' => file_get_contents($uploadFile)
            );

            // Execute remote upload
            $curl = curl_init();
            $url="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[bucket_name]/o?uploadType=media&name=".$filename;
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $authheaders);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $uploadRequest);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            echo $response;

        }
    }
?>
```

I am uploading image through this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[Image Number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwGZp.png)

Look at the image number 1, the file is getting uploaded successfully. But when I click on it to view it, it shows like in image number 2.

[Image Number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTpiW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload#example_sending_a_simple_upload_request) the body of the request (aka your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`) should only contain the `[JPEG_DATA]` (aka just your `file_get_contents($uploadFile)`).

But in your sample, you are giving the body an array of `'fileName'` and `'fileData'` which are not even valid [body property metadata names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request-body) for the [Google Cloud Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/).

Google Cloud Storage then interprets this array of `'fileName'` and `'fileData'` as the actual `[JPEG_DATA]`, and renders it as a JPEG file that returns as the small square image you always see.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is indeed showing in [Image Number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTpiW.png) on your browser.

Since your image dimensions are small, it is not easily visible in your browser. In [your uploaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTpiW.png), it is showing up a small white box with four boxes within (2 white, 2 gray). You can zoom in to confirm. I believe that is the image you uploaded.

You can try uploading a different image of slightly bigger dimensions and confirm if it is working.

Comment: I tried uploading the image of larger dimensions but still it shows the same